# ¿COMO AGREGO UN AUDIO DE MP3 EN BLAZOR?

Tags: c#, blazor

estoy usando blazor, cree un juego básico tipo golpea al topo cuando de click a la imagen correcta esto sumara un punto, lo que quiero hacer ahora es cuando sume un punto suene un archivo .mp3 (un sonido) estoy usando WMPLib (lo exporte con using) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al ejecutar mi programa sale un error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya agregue la dependencias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme. Si lo estoy haciendo de la manera incorrecta, agradecería me explicaran cómo hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Haz el [tour] y lee [ask]: agrega tu código y errores como texto con formato, para mejor legibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo, estás utilizando un componente COM y no es compatible con aplicaciones Blazor.
Puedes utilizar Interoperabilidad con JavaScript para acceder a un elemento audio e invocar el método play para emitir el sonido.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que puedes colocar en un componente razor para probar.

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<audio id="sound" src="sounds/ring.mp3"></audio>

<button  @onclick="Play">Play!</button>
@code{
    void Play()
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", 
            "document.getElementById(\'sound\').play();");
    }
}
```